# Migrating from IIS 5.1 to Apache 2.11, how do I move/translate ISAPI filters into Apache?

Tags: apache, iis, isapi

Maybe this isn't even a valid question, so any help would be good.

Comment: It seems that those ISAPI filters can do quite a lot. It would be better of you told us what you are currently using them for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISAPI is a technology that built upon IIS program interfaces. You cant use ISAPI filters with Apache. So you have to find appropriate analogs for these filters (apache modules).